# I have trouble incrementing. Why?

Tags: java, increment

What's wrong with this? Specifically, what's wrong with `intCount.put(i, intCount.get(i)++)`?

```
public static Map<Integer, Integer> countNumbers(List<Integer> list) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> intCount = new TreeMap<>();
    for (Integer i : list) {
      if (intCount.get(i) == null) {
        intCount.put(i, 1);
      } else {
        intCount.put(i, ++intCount.get(i));
      }
    }
    return intCount;
  }
```

This works, on the other hand

```
public static Map<Integer, Integer> countNumbers(List<Integer> list) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> intCount = new TreeMap<>();
    for (Integer i : list) {
      if (intCount.get(i) == null) {
        intCount.put(i, 1);
      } else {
        intCount.put(i, intCount.get(i) + 1);
      }
    }
    return intCount;
  }
```

Does it mean I can't increment `Integer`s, only `int` primitives? The problem is when I cast `Integer` into its respective primitive (or rather, an `Integer` returning method into its respective primitive) like this

```
intCount.put(i, ++(int)(intCount.get(i)));
```

it doesn't work either! Why?

> Main.java:30: error: unexpected type
>
> intCount.put(i, ++(int)(intCount.get(i)));
>
> ^
> required: variable
>
> found: value
>
> 1 error

Comment: In the 1st case, the code tries to increment a value / literal, not a variable. Pre- and postincrement can only be executed on variables, not values / literals.

Comment: Think of it this way: what would be the semantics of, for example, `1++`? `1` is a literal, there is nothing to "assign the value back to". Or if there were, the literal `1` would now represent the value `2`, which would be confusing as heck.

Answer (score 2):

`intCount.get(i)` gets a value, there is no variable to increment. Regardless, I would remove the `if` and `else` entirely and use [`Map.getOrDefault(Object, V)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-) like

```
intCount.put(i, intCount.getOrDefault(i, 0) + 1);
```

Comment: Or maybe even more concise: `intCount.merge(i, 1, Integer::sum);`

Comment: Or maybe even `intCount.compute(1, v -> v == null ? 1 : v + 1)` ... if you need the new counter value.